# PDOException: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, drupal, exception

**Drupal 7**

I am getting this error whenever I visit Configuration > Search and Metadata > URL aliases > Patterns (localhost/admin/config/search/path/patterns)

**Original**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {variable} variable WHERE (
>   (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => drupal_css_cache_files ) in
>   variable_set() (line 991 of
>   /home/www/icts-website/includes/bootstrap.inc).

**Additional**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables,
>   severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => php
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => %type: !message in %function (line %line
>   of %file). [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =>
>   a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:12:"PDOException";s:8:"!message";s:235:"SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression
>   FROM {variable} variable WHERE ( (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
>   ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => drupal_css_cache_files
>   )
>   ";s:9:"%function";s:14:"variable_set()";s:5:"%file";s:45:"/home/www/icts-website/includes/bootstrap.inc";s:5:"%line";i:991;s:14:"severity_level";i:3;}
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =>
>   http://localhost/admin/config/search/path/patterns
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => http://localhost/
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 10.0.8.14 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] =>
>   1444714070 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 160 of
>   /home/www/icts-website/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

**Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => 399784779561c9655b48719.42544548 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of /home/www/icts-website/includes/lock.inc).

I googled the solution and I also increased the max_allowed_packet to 32M but still the error page persist.

I will really appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

`my.cnf` file details is given below:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

# include all files from the config directory
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

I am using CentOS 7 and MySQL.

Comment: This usually indicates a lack of resources available to mySQL. The max_allowed_packet_size is only one variable. Could you post your my.cnf file (with any sensitive info removed) so we can see what's up?

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I have included the my.cnf file in question description.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this error is related to parsing of large amount of data, so database fails as it can't handle such sizes due the given limits, therefore the server timing out and closing the connection.

To fix it, you need to increase further up the value of `max_allowed_packet` in your `my.cnf` (e.g. `~/.my.cnf`) under `[mysqld]` section, e.g.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

Try with `256M`, if won't help, try increasing further more (e.g. `1G`).

In your case, I think `max_allowed_packet` should be under `[mysqld]` section specifically, not under `[mysqld_safe]`, so settings are applied to the right component.

See: [B.5.2.9 MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) for more detailed information.

Another thing is that in this particular case it happens in shutdown function (which is after Drupal finished the processing of the site), therefore it could be related to some cron or debugging tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your my.cnf is missing some entries for InnoDB that might help

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 180
```

I have these additional lines in my MySQL config. It may or may not be the solution for you, but it is definitely worth a try. Let me know if this doesn't help. You may need to tweak these values a bit depending on your environment.

-- Don't forget to restart MySQL after making changes to my.cnf.

Comment: Dear Quint, thanks you for your help. I have edited the my.cnf and included the parameters but the errors still persist. I disable and uninstall the pathauto module and cleared the cache. After installing again, the error still persist. The error is coming only on pathout (Pattern tab) module.

Comment: I did a little more poking around and found out that the entity_token module can cause this problem. It generates a huge number of tokens (https://www.drupal.org/node/1334104) that causes mysql to choke. The suggested workaround is to set the max_allowed_packet_size to = 100M. Are you using the entiity_token module?

Comment: Dear Quint, I am really thankful to you and for your prompt reply.
I am using entity_token module. I also increased max_allowed_packet_size to = 100M, but the error still persist.

Comment: Dear Quint, You were completely right. I disabled and uninstalled entity_token and this problem is resolve. I need entity_token module for Rules, but even after increasing max_allowed_packet_size to 100M, the problem still persist. Please share your expert advice which will help me in enabling entity_token module and other features.

Thanks a ton for all your help and time.

Comment: You can try to increase the memory again (restarting mysql after each change) or you can try the suggestion at https://www.drupal.org/node/1058912#comment-4801902, which can be implemented in a custom module.